# How to define width AND use max-width

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to make my images smaller as the window size gets smaller.

However, I have to define the size of these two images by width, yet because 'max-width' overrides 'width' then it makes the images really small? I need to use 'max-width' to resize my images. However, I have two images on the left hand side that I have used both width and max-width and its width is defined and it resizes? What am I doing wrong with the other two?

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9;
}
/* css for the two larger images on the left-hand side*/

#imageleft {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
}
/* css for the two smaller images on the right-hand side*/

#imageright {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- large images to left -->
<div id="imageleft">
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="images/photo-1464375117522-1311d6a5b81f.jpeg" alt="Guitar image" style="max-width:100%; width:600px;height:400px">
  </a>
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="images/photo-1470020618177-f49a96241ae7.jpeg" alt="Fire breather" style="max-width:100%; width: 300px;height: 400px">
  </a>
</div>

<!-- small images to the right -->
<div id="imageright">
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="images/photo-1472653431158-6364773b2a56.jpeg" alt="festival" style=" max-width: 100%; height: 200px">
  </a>
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="images/photo-1473396413399-6717ef7c4093.jpeg" alt="stage view" style="width:291px; max-width: 100%;height: 196px">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest doing some research into media queries in CSS, as that's the preferred way of "resizing images as the window size gets smaller". Also, it's unclear why you have some properties defined in a stylesheet and some inline.

Comment: It is unclear what layout you want to accomplish.

Comment: You don't have any `max-width` properties in your code. Also, try to provide *real* (dummy) images so we can test.

Comment: In general... `width: 100%; max-width: (actual image width);` in the style sheet so they can be accessed by media queries easily if needed... not inline.

Answer (score 0):

@helpme123 I really didn't get what kind of layout you desire to achieve. Could you change your post and provide an example of it, please?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `width` and `max-width` together, it's usually because you are giving the element a width *relative to its parent (or the viewport or the current font-size or the base font-size)*, but you also want to explicitly state an absolute width, beyond which the element should not widen.

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
width: 90%;
padding: 12px;
}

.parent {
max-width: 1000px;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.child {
max-width: 600px;
background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
}

.grandchild {
max-width: 400px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
<div class="grandchild">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If you run the example in a full window and shrink the window size and then gradually grow it, you'll see that the divs each widen relative to their parent... until they reach their `max-width`, after which they stop widening.